# Problem with table notes in a landscape ThreePartTable

Tags: threeparttable, ltablex, threeparttablex, tablenotes

I have a long paper with a landscape table, spread in 2 pages. For that table I'm using `afterpage` `ltablex` `threeparttablex` and `threeparttable` packages. I made a MWE, however it worked perfectly. So I'm not sure what is happening on the original file. When the table note has more than 1 line, the table disappears remaining only the last line of the note.

Here the MWE with correct notes

```
\documentclass[review,a4paper]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    bookmarksnumbered,
    citecolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksopen=true}
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
left=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
right=2.5cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{subfig}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\sloppy
\begin{document}%
\Blindtext
\linenumbers
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
{\footnotesize%
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXXX}
\toprule
Head 1\tnotex{a}&
Head 2\tnotex{b}&
Head 3\tnotex{c}&
Head 4\tnotex{d}\\
\midrule
\blindtext&\blindtext&\blindtext&\blindtext\\
\blindtext&\blindtext&\blindtext&\blindtext\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] \label{a} Text
\item[b] \label{b} Text
\item[c] \label{c} Text
\item[d] \label{d} \blindtext
\end{tablenotes}
\end{ThreePartTable}
}
\end{landscape}%
}%
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same structure is being used in the original paper, however this is happening:

The black rectangles are information, and the rest of the table is gone, only the last line of the notes appears.

[image]

`natbib`, `hyperref` or any other packages could be interferring?

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` far, far too early. It likes to be loaded late with few exceptions (most notably `cleveref` which must come after). Are you really using `\sloppy` for your entire document? Yuck.

Comment: If your code doesn't reproduce the problem, it cannot be a simple matter of those packages interfering. It must be, at least in part, a result of the code you have which we don't. That is going to make it extremely difficult - probably impossible - to help.

Comment: You can't use `tablenotes` with a long table. You need to use `TableNotes` *first* and then `\insertTableNotes`. See `threeparttablex`'s manual for details and examples.